# Only root Routing working [Lumen laravel ]

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, lumen, laravel-5.4

I have Installed a fresh lumen framework. But it routes only '/' routing. 
On any other routing it returns only '/' homepage.

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

my `web.php` is  like this

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {     return " it is working";
 });

$app->get('hello', function () use ($app) {     return "it is not working";
});
```

**PS** :- `AllowOverride` is set `All` in httpd.conf file.

Comment: Can you show us your ``web.php`` code? Also, what development setup are you running? ``php artisan serve``, homestead? We need a little bit more information to help you.

Comment: @Mark I have updated the question with web.php, yes it is homestead development.

Comment: @Mark  Problem is only with lumen 5.4, working well with 5.3 and 5.2..!!

Answer (score 0):

This shows that you 've no problem in your `.htaccess` file , 
Probably you are using PHP below **5.5.9** , 
Try updating your **vagrant box** with the latest updates

```
vagrant box update
```

Before doing this , backup your existing **files**

Or you can check out the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead#upgrading-to-php-7) on how to do it